# How to inspect javascript using Firefox developer tools

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-developer-tools

On a webpage I have a `"onclick"` event in a `<div>` element. Right clicking it on Firefox and inspecting it brings up the dev console. At this point I see the function it is being called but I'm unable to lookup the code or the file that this function is pointing to, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body of the javascript function can be found in respective .js library. In developer's tool, click the tab "Debugger". It lists all .js files which might contain the function you are looking for.

Comment: I tried that but the page has hundreds on scripts, I need to "find function" if the function is being executed the browser must know on what file it is but cannot locate it.

Comment: @S.Redrum You answer below is spot on. I figured it out but rather late in posting here.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer while trying, it seems I were using # rather than @ which is used to lookup a function definition!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried firebug add on for Firefox?
I think it is clearer to see it with firebug. I'm sorry if it's not what you are looking for, because i can't suggest it on comment

Comment: I can try to install it but do you know the steps to lookup a function?

Comment: I don't know if this answer your question.. just right click on the page and click the 'inspect with firebug'. Then choose the 'script' tab below.

for the complete doc, see here: https://getfirebug.com/javascript